# Why is my gpio access from user space slower?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, gpio

I did some research on how good I am able to access a gpio while other heavy tasks are executed. With a first test I toggeled a gpio pin from user space using the libgpiod API. With a second test I toggeled the pin from kernel space using the API included with . I measured the frequency with an oscilloscope. The frequency I should measure theoretically is 31.25Hz. But I get this value only when toggeling the pin from kernel space. From user space I nearly get just half the value.

My explanation therefore is that from user space there are more software layers between my code and the pin, which delays my signal.

So my questions are: Am I right? Are there additional things which could influence it? And is there some documentation (man page, etc.) or something similar which approve my assumption?

I use a simple shell script in user space

```
while true; do
  gpioset GPIOE 12=1
  sleep 0.016
  gpioset GPIOE 12=0
  sleep 0.016
done
```

EDIT: I am using openSTLinux with kernel version 4.19 on the STM32MP157c-dk2 board

Comment: What system are you on: OS and hardware.

Comment: Yes there is an overhead to calling from user-space to kernel. Sometimes there will be a way to batch up commands. e.g. most Audio drivers (that do similar thing), allow the user-space to pass several seconds of signal to the kernel in one call.

Comment: Where do you get the theoretical maximum of 31.25 Hz?  That seems pretty slow.  Especially to be affected userspace / kernel space overhead.

Comment: You need to show us the user space code ...

Comment: I use a delay of 16µs between each set and clear of the pin. That should result in a frequency of 31.25Hz. When I run it as kernel thread, I get that value. When I run it in user space, I get far less.

Comment: You run a program to control the I/O pin and possibly another to delay (if sleep is not builtin). How long do you think it takes to create a new process (fork) and load the program (exec)? My guess is that it would be significant compared to your desired delay (ie of the same order) ... this could easily explain the difference